# Using Autowired to create object instances

Tags: java, autowired

I'm trying to understand `@Autowired`.

If I have a class which creates an instance of `OutboundObject` it will traditionally look like this:

```
DecodeOutbound decodeOutbound = new DecodeOutbound();
```

Can I instead just use the below code?

```
@Autowired
DecodeOutbound decodeOutbound;
```

Comment: Yes, but for this to work you need to annotate your class `DecodeOutbound` with either of these depending on your class functionality  `@Component`  `@Service`  `@Configuration`  `@Repository` etc.. now the `@Autowire` annotation will inject your bean in the class you are using it in.  Read docs for clarity : https://springframework.guru/spring-framework-annotations/

Comment: Also worth noting the default scope for spring beans is `singleton`. Autowiring the same bean class into multiple (other) beans will all reference a single instance of the bean.

Comment: OK, thanks. I should have said. My class has `@Configuration`.